# Imputing missing Dates in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

```
df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/MJjpYqLzv08xAkjqLp1ga1Aq/Historical_Data.csv')
df.head()

    Date        Article_ID   Country_Code   Sold_Units
0   20170817        1132       AT               1
1   20170818        1132       AT               1
2   20170821        1132       AT               1
3   20170822        1132       AT               1
4   20170906        1132       AT               1
```

I have the above-given DataFrame. Note that the Date column is of type int64 and has missing dates 19th and 20th.

I want to bring it to the format yyyy-mm-dd and impute the missing dates with  values 0 in Article ID, Outlet Code and Sold Units.

So far I have tried:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

to get the dates in the required format.

```
    Date         Article_ID  Outlet_Code   Sold_Units
0   2017-08-17      1132       AT               1
1   2017-08-18      1132       AT               1
2   2017-08-21      1132       AT               1
3   2017-08-22      1132       AT               1
4   2017-09-06      1132       AT               1
```

However, how do I impute the missing dates of 19th and 20th and impute the rows with 0s under the newly added date rows?

Here is a snippet of what I have done which is returning a value error: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) 
to reindex after deleting duplicates and then adding duplicate data and sorting:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d')
df2=df[df.duplicated('Date')].set_index('Date')
new_df=df.drop_duplicates('Date').set_index('Date').asfreq('D',fill_value=0)
new_df=new_df.append(df2).sort_index().reset_index()
print(new_df)

         Date  Article_ID Country_Code  Sold_Units
0  2017-08-17        1132           AT           1
1  2017-08-17        1132           AT           1
2  2017-08-18        1132           AT           1
3  2017-08-19           0            0           0
4  2017-08-20           0            0           0
5  2017-08-21        1132           AT           1
6  2017-08-22        1132           AT           1
7  2017-08-23           0            0           0
8  2017-08-24           0            0           0
9  2017-08-25           0            0           0
10 2017-08-26           0            0           0
11 2017-08-27           0            0           0
12 2017-08-28           0            0           0
13 2017-08-29           0            0           0
14 2017-08-30           0            0           0
15 2017-08-31           0            0           0
16 2017-09-01           0            0           0
17 2017-09-02           0            0           0
18 2017-09-03           0            0           0
19 2017-09-04           0            0           0
20 2017-09-05           0            0           0
21 2017-09-06        1132           AT           1
```

Comment: I get this error while trying your code. ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/MJjpYqLzv08xAkjqLp1ga1Aq/Historical_Data.csv') 

This is the dataset.

Comment: Using Groupby(level=0) command is only adding Level_0 before the Date column.

Comment: I have added my output image which is returning the value error.

Comment: I have updated the code. The strategy can be to reindex without duplicate rows and add these later. Please check this attempt :)

Comment: Update check now

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: The current version I am using is 0.25.1

Comment: Then you will not have problems with the version. Have you tried this code?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment. I'll revert about it. Really appreciate your patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'].astype(str), format='%Y-%m-%d',errors='coerce')
```

You don't miss your missing date, but it is represented by NaT.

You've got something like this

```
       Date  Article_ID Outlet_Code  Sold_Units
 0 2017-08-17        1132          AT           1
 1 2017-08-18        1132          AT           1
 2        NaT        1132          AT           1
```

Comment: I want the imputed date to be appended to the dataframe.

Comment: What date? If you don't have the value, because it's missing, you are faking one. You can suppose one, because your data seems ordered, but you can't be 100% sure.

Comment: In the dataframe, 19th and 20th should be added as they are missing dates. And the values against the aritcle code and sold units should be 0.

Comment: I didn't use the complete dataframe, I used just your first 3 records and left the data null on the 3rd one. What "errors = 'coerce' " does is to ignore the errors, and transform your data, no matter what.

Comment: I've added the dataset for you in the question. You could go through it in your notebook. Most of my tries gives me a value error.

Comment: Now I see that you were talking about gaps between dates. I've assumed it was NaN values in your date column. My bad, sorry. But I see someone already provided an effective answer.